# Firebase blocks other incoming HTTP post

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, authentication

I am using Firebase auth on a Node.js application in combination with express. But, I run into a problem. An HTTP post (which I am using to trigger a function) is blocked by Firebase because it doesn't have the right cookies.

Can I whitelist that IP address somewhere? Does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: Can you show the function? Or the error? Generally, if you're not on the paid plan you're not allow external networking i.e interactions with services outside of firebase

Comment: I am using `app.post('/', function(request) {});` for receiving the HTTP post. 

This is the error, in my Node.js server console.log: 
`5|VC FAVOR |     at cookieParser (/home/debian/projects/favorietfm_visualradio/node_modules/cookie-parser/index.js:57:14)
5|VC FAVOR | ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token`